# Retrieve and write TLS CRT kubernetes secret to another pod in Helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-kafka-connect, kubernetes-secrets

I have a Kubernetes cluster with Elasticsearch currently deployed.

The Elasticsearch coordinator node is accessible behind a service via a `ClusterIP` over HTTPS. It uses a self-signed TLS certificate.

I can retrieve the value of the CA:

```sh
kubectl get secret \
    -n elasticsearch elasticsearch-coordinating-only-crt \
    -o jsonpath="{.data.ca\.crt}" | base64 -d
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIjCCAgqgAwIBAgIRANkAx51S
...
...
```

I need to provide this as a `ca.crt` to other app deployments.

> Note: The Elasticsearch deployment is an an `elasticsearch` Kubernetes namespace. New deployments will be in different namespaces.

An example of this is a deployment of kafka that includes a [kafka-connect-elasticsearch/](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/configuration_options.html#security) sink. The sink connector uses configuration such as:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
  labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
data:
  connect-standalone-custom.properties: |-
    bootstrap.servers={{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-0.{{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-headless.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.{{ .Values.clusterDomain }}:{{ .Values.service.port }}
    key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    value.converter.schemas.enable=false
    offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
    offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    plugin.path=/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins
  elasticsearch.properties: |-
    name=elasticsearch-sink
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
    tasks.max=4
    topics=syslog,nginx
    key.ignore=true
    schema.ignore=true
    connection.url=https://elasticsearch-coordinating-only.elasticsearch:9200
    type.name=kafka-connect
    connection.username=elastic
    connection.password=xxxxxxxx
    elastic.security.protocol=SSL
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/certs/elasticsearch-ca.crt
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type=PEM
```

Notice the `elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/ssl/certs/elasticsearch-ca.crt`; that's the file I need to put inside the `kafka`-based container.

**What's the optimal way to do that with Helm templates?**

Currently I have a fork of https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka. It adds 3 new templates under `templates/`:

- kafka-connect-elasticsearch-configmap.yaml
- kafka-connect-svc.yaml
- kafka-connect.yaml

The `configmap` is shown above.  The `kafka-connect.yaml` Deployment looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
  labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: {{- include "common.labels.matchLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
      app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 8 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: connect
          image: REDACTED.dkr.ecr.REDACTED.amazonaws.com/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -ec
            - bin/connect-standalone.sh custom-config/connect-standalone-custom.properties custom-config/elasticsearch.properties
          ports:
            - name: connector
              containerPort: 8083
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configuration
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/kafka/custom-config
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: configuration
          configMap:
            name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
```

**How can I modify these Kafka Helm charts to allow them to retrieve the value for `kubectl get secret -n elasticsearch elasticsearch-coordinating-only-crt -o jsonpath="{.data.ca\.crt}" | base64 -d` and write its content to `/etc/ssl/certs/elasticsearch-ca.crt` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working and learned a few things in the process:

- Secret resources reside in a namespace. Secrets can only be referenced by Pods in that same namespace. ([ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)). Therefore, I switched to using a shared namespace for elasticsearch + kafka
- The secret can be used in a straightforward way as documented at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets. This is not a Helm-specific but rather core Kubernetes feature

In my case this looked like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
  labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: {{- include "common.labels.matchLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
      app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 8 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: connector
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: connect
          image: REDACTED.dkr.ecr.REDACTED.amazonaws.com/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -ec
            - bin/connect-standalone.sh custom-config/connect-standalone-custom.properties custom-config/elasticsearch.properties
          ports:
            - name: connector
              containerPort: 8083
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configuration
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/kafka/custom-config
            - name: ca
              mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
              readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: configuration
          configMap:
            name: {{ include "kafka.fullname" . }}-connect
        - name: ca
          secret:
            secretName: elasticsearch-coordinating-only-crt
```

This gets the `kafka-connect` pod up and running, and I can validate the certs are written there also:

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it -n elasticsearch kafka-connect-c4f4d7dbd-wbxfq \
    -- ls -1 /etc/ssl/certs

ca.crt
tls.crt
tls.key
```